# Format a 0 value in Excel as - using PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

How can I apply a format to a cell or range of cells to have them display - instead of 0, as Excel does? I am using the PHPExcel library to create the Excel workbook that is exported

For example, in the source workbook that I am recreating in PHP I have the cells as such:
[image]

On my export for this section, I have:
[image]

I need the cells that have a value of "0" to display as "-". Note the cell should still contain the value "0", I assume the cells are displayed as "-" because Excel applies a default format to its cells.

Also, is there a way to apply a default border to all cells (instead of applying a border to each cell individually), for example the screenshot from my export shows that empty (white) cells still have a grey border, but the source workbook's empty cells do not have a border. (Such empty cells will not be referenced in the data matrix I supply to PHP to create the sheet from)

Comment: Unclear what you're asking.... PHPExcel will store what you ask it to in a cell, store a `0` and it will display a `0`, store an empty string or a null and it won't display a `0`.... if it is displaying a `0`, then you must be doing something else, but I can't guess what

Comment: Hi @MarkBaker, I updated the question to make it more clear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a "multi-expression" number format mask

MS Excel supports format masks that allow different masking for different values in a cell.

A format mask of

```
#,##0;-#,##0;"-"
```

will display using a mask of `#,##0` for values `> 0`, a mask of `-#,##0;` for values `< 0`, and `-` for `0` values